# Average using *args and from attribute of class

Tags: python, python-3.x

the line that i specifically need help with is

```
sum += student_{num}.mark
```

I want to be able to pass through as many students as necessary to figure out the average of their marks. I want to run a loop that checks for the marks of the students that have been inputted.

the whole program for context i guess

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, first, last, grade, phone, mark, birthyear):
       self.first = first
       self.last = last
       self.grade = grade
       self.phone = phone
       self.mark = mark
       self.birthyear = birthyear
       self

   def email(self):
       self.email = self.last + self.first[0] + '@school.ca'
       print(self.email)

   def next_course(self):
       print("Hi, would you like to know what your next course is?")
       student_answer = input()
       if student_answer == "yes":
           student_name = input("What is your name?")
           if student_name == student_1.first:
               print("Your next class is cooking")
           elif student_name == student_2.first:
               print("Your next class is math")
           elif student_name == student_3.first:
               print("Your next class is phys. ed.")
           else:
               print("You aren't registered at this school")





   def average(*args):
       print(len(args))
       sum = 0
       for num in range(1, len(args)):
           sum += student_{num}.mark
       print(sum)



student_1 = Student('Jo', 'Oh', 11, 867 - 5309, 96, 2004)
student_2 = Student('Alex', 'Smith', 12, 888-888, 87, 2003)
student_3 = Student('Thor', 'Superhero', 12, 123-4567, 50, 2003)

Student.average(student_1, student_2, student_3)


Student.email(student_1)
Student.next_course(student_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For average, you can really just write

```
def average(*args):
    return sum([student.mark for student in args]) / len(args)
```

Note that here I use the `sum` function as intended. In your code, you shadow this function by writing it as a variable name, which is always a bad idea. Even if you don't intend to use `sum` right now, you shouldn't shadow it.

Still, let's resolve the issues you faced:

```
def average(*args):
    print(len(args))
    sum = 0
    for num in range(1, len(args) + 1):
        sum += eval(f"student_{num}").mark
    print(sum / len(args))
```

Here, `eval` evaluates `student_{num}` to its actual value in the code (but only because we included the `f` at the beginning of the string, which tells python to include the value of `num` there). Note also that you need to go to `len(args) + 1` because students start at 1, not 0 here. Note finally that this average method you define doesn't actually average the students that it's provided, it will always do `student_1`, `student_2`, etc... until the length of `args`. So if you gave it `student_4` and `student_5`, it would still average `student_1` and `student_2` because of how the for loop is defined.